# Is it possible to use a force touch (3D Touch) with the standard controller UIImagePickerController?

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, force-touch

I try by force pressing in UIImagePickerController to get the image, but instead of calling the didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo I get nothing.

Additional info:

When I try to force pressing on the photo, I get a messages:

"*** error reading settings archive file: ISRootSettings: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/0A2D79B3-C024-45F0-BD80-30B866F98558/Documents/{Bundle_ID}.settings/ISRootSettings_10.plist"

"Use -removeDeferredKeyObserver: instead of -removeKeyObserver:".

It's weird.

Comment: have you understand what cause that log `-removeDeferredKeyObserver: instead of -removeKeyObserver`