# Use -removeDeferredKeyObserver: instead of -removeKeyObserver

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter, mbprogresshud, swift2

Can't find method with cause this log message.

```
2016-05-24 13:12:44.451 MYAPPNAME[33530:7289718] Use -removeDeferredKeyObserver: instead of -removeKeyObserver:
```

Any suggestion how to find method? Actually what is `[33530:7289718]` information.

What I've tried:

1. Search trough the project with key word `removeKeyObserver`
2. Search using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37391609/xcode-7-found-a-place-where-it-prints-a-line-with-a-log-error)
3. I added breakpoints everywhere in the project where I `removeObserver`. Note. I searched removeObserver because I have not found `removeKeyObserver` word. I tried to debug it and seems it's connected to some classes where we use PHLivePhoto. But I have not found the line which call `removeKeyObserver`

   4. Also there is not a lot links in the web regarding this log. I found one more [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37252524/is-it-possible-to-use-a-force-touch-3d-touch-with-the-standard-controller-uiim) where we can see the same log.

Also I have MBProgressHud and seems there are also some related calls.

Also I found some maybe helpful [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7270502/how-to-log-all-methods-used-in-ios-app) that I can use to set debug breakpoint. How can I specify breakpoint using `removeKeyObserver`